# Where is SVN caching the hostname?

Tags: svn, caching, tortoisesvn

When I perform a SVN checkout and specify a hostname, SVN is attempting to resolve a hostname to an old repo that I no longer use. I cannot find where this old hostname (codespaces.com) is being cached.

Checkout from http://mysubdomain.unfuddle.com/svn/, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
OPTIONS of 'http://mysubdomain.unfuddle.com/svn/': Could not resolve 
hostname `https://svn.codespaces.com/my-old-project/': The requested name is valid, 
but no data of the requested type was found.
 (http://mysubdomain.unfuddle.com)

I have uninstalled TortoiseSVN and SVN itself. And reinstalled them one by one. I have searched the C drive and the registry for the string literal codespaces.com - to no avail.

This has had me banging my head on the table for 2 full days and I am at my wits end. Can anybody shed some light on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try clearing the arp cache `netsh interface ip delete arpcache`

Comment: I am on Windows 7, TortoiseSVN 1.6.12, Build 20536 - 64 Bit, 
Subversion 1.6.15,

Comment: what does `ping mysubdomain.unfuddle.com` print?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>ping mydubdomain.unfuddle.com

Pinging server-16.unfuddle.com [184.72.227.87] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out. (x4)

Comment: @Eddy, it's not a problem relating to subversion then. I believe the people over at serverfault.com can help you better.

Comment: Could not resolve hostname **`https://svn.codespaces.com/my-old-project/'**. The unfuddle domain isn't the problem. Something else fishy is going on (where does this other domain name come from?).

Comment: What happens if you visit http://mysubdomain.unfuddle.com/svn/ with a webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

The host is stored in `.svn/entries`.

Comment: I am unable to check out - so a .svn folder is never created

Comment: Indeed so desperate was I to find the source of this manic hostname caching I have deleted every .svn folder on this hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try relocating? Read [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html) page to know how to do this with Tortoisse.

Comment: Eddy is trying to __checkout__, not working with an existing checkout.

Comment: Relocate scans all entries files in the .svn folders and changes the URL of the entries to the new value. However my issue occurs when I attempt to checkout or import. At this stage there are no .svn folders in existence.